# How to Read each .ini Section

Tags: vb.net, listview, ini

I managed to get a class which writes and reads to an INI file. Below is the code for it:

```
Public Class IniFile
' API functions
Private Declare Ansi Function GetPrivateProfileString _
  Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA" _
  (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
  ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpDefault As String, _
  ByVal lpReturnedString As System.Text.StringBuilder, _
  ByVal nSize As Integer, ByVal lpFileName As String) _
  As Integer
Private Declare Ansi Function WritePrivateProfileString _
  Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "WritePrivateProfileStringA" _
  (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
  ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpString As String, _
  ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
Private Declare Ansi Function GetPrivateProfileInt _
  Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetPrivateProfileIntA" _
  (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
  ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal nDefault As Integer, _
  ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
Private Declare Ansi Function FlushPrivateProfileString _
  Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "WritePrivateProfileStringA" _
  (ByVal lpApplicationName As Integer, _
  ByVal lpKeyName As Integer, ByVal lpString As Integer, _
  ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
Dim strFilename As String

' Constructor, accepting a filename
Public Sub New(ByVal Filename As String)
    strFilename = Filename
End Sub

' Read-only filename property
ReadOnly Property FileName() As String
    Get
        Return strFilename
    End Get
End Property

Public Function GetString(ByVal Section As String, _
  ByVal Key As String, ByVal [Default] As String) As String
    ' Returns a string from your INI file
    Dim intCharCount As Integer
    Dim objResult As New System.Text.StringBuilder(256)
    intCharCount = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, _
       [Default], objResult, objResult.Capacity, strFilename)
    If intCharCount > 0 Then GetString = _
       Left(objResult.ToString, intCharCount)
End Function

Public Function GetInteger(ByVal Section As String, _
  ByVal Key As String, ByVal [Default] As Integer) As Integer
    ' Returns an integer from your INI file
    Return GetPrivateProfileInt(Section, Key, _
       [Default], strFilename)
End Function

Public Function GetBoolean(ByVal Section As String, _
  ByVal Key As String, ByVal [Default] As Boolean) As Boolean
    ' Returns a boolean from your INI file
    Return (GetPrivateProfileInt(Section, Key, _
       CInt([Default]), strFilename) = 1)
End Function

Public Sub WriteString(ByVal Section As String, _
  ByVal Key As String, ByVal Value As String)
    ' Writes a string to your INI file
    WritePrivateProfileString(Section, Key, Value, strFilename)
    Flush()
End Sub

Public Sub WriteInteger(ByVal Section As String, _
  ByVal Key As String, ByVal Value As Integer)
    ' Writes an integer to your INI file
    WriteString(Section, Key, CStr(Value))
    Flush()
End Sub

Public Sub WriteBoolean(ByVal Section As String, _
  ByVal Key As String, ByVal Value As Boolean)
    ' Writes a boolean to your INI file
    WriteString(Section, Key, CStr(CInt(Value)))
    Flush()
End Sub

Private Sub Flush()
    ' Stores all the cached changes to your INI file
    FlushPrivateProfileString(0, 0, 0, strFilename)
End Sub
End Class
```

I've used this to write to an INI file. The output is:

```
[AF23AE0F]
Title=Title
Username=Username
[4C347E51]
Title=Title
Username=Username
```

The Section contains a specific ID which is assigned to the keys. e.g. Once i input "AF23AE0F" as the section it will get the keys related to section "AF23AE0F". Since I have multiple sections I want to read each section and under each section get the keys and add them to a Listview.

```
ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {ID, Title, Username}))
```

Above is the code which I use to add to the listview, this method adds items to each column..
In order to get the section I use:

```
 Dim objIniFile As New IniFile("C:\data.ini")
 objIniFile.GetString("Get Each Section ID", "Title", "Get Value related to 'Title'")
```

Through a `For Each` statement I expect to be getting each section and reading the ID and adding it to the method above and that as a result will read each key.

How can I read each section and get the keys and add them to the listview?

Answer (score 1):

Well, since it seems like you are not actually forced to use .ini files, why don't you make a 20 year leap forward in time and use XML-serialization to read and write your data to a structured file?

```
Module Module1
    Private Sub WriteUsers(Filename As String)
        'Create an example user list
        Dim Users As New List(Of User)
        Users.Add(New User With {.ID = "JAOIJSFL", .Title = "Hello", .Username = "Guy 1"})
        Users.Add(New User With {.ID = "LKGJASOI", .Title = "World", .Username = "Guy 2"})

        'Initialize a new XmlSerializer with the type of data you want to write
        Dim Serializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of User)))
        'Create the file and write the list to it
        Using fs As New IO.FileStream(Filename, IO.FileMode.Create)
            Serializer.Serialize(fs, Users)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Function ReadUsers(Filename As String) As List(Of User)
        'Initialize a new XmlSerializer with the type of data you want to read
        Dim Serializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of User)))
        'Open the input file, read and return the data
        Using fs As New IO.FileStream(Filename, IO.FileMode.Open)
            Return CType(Serializer.Deserialize(fs), List(Of User))
        End Using
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        'Write data
        WriteUsers("C:\test\test.xml")
        'Read the written data back
        Dim users As List(Of User) = ReadUsers("C:\test\test.xml")
        'Output the results
        For Each u As User In users
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("ID: {0}, Title: {1}, Name: {2}", u.ID, u.Title, u.Username))
        Next
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class User
    'This class contains all the information about each 'section' that you need
    Public Property ID As String
    Public Property Username As String
    Public Property Title As String
End Class
```

This uses automatic generation of an XML document to write a list of a custom class that contain your information to a file. It then can directly reproduce this list from the file again into a handy list. It has quite a lot of advantages over an ini-file.